# Substitute any other character except for a specific pattern in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I have text files with lines like this:

```
U_town/u_LN0_pk_LN3_bnb_LN155/DD0 U_DESIGN/u_LNxx_pk_LN99_bnb_LN151_LN11_/DD5
U_master/u_LN999_pk_LN767888_bnb_LN9772/Dnn111 u_LN999_pk_LN767888_bnb_LN9772_LN9999_LN11/DD
...
```

I am trying to substitute any other character except for `/` to nothing and keep a word with pattern `_LN\d+_` with Perl one-liner.

So the edited version would look like:

```
/_LN0__LN3__LN155/ /_LN99__LN151_LN11_/
/_LN999__LN767888_/ _LN999__LN767888__LN9772_LN9999_/
```

I tried below which returned empty lines

```
perl -pe 's/(?! _LN\d+_)[^\/].+//g' file
```

Below returned only '/'.

```
perl -pe 's/(?! _LN\d+_)\w+//g' file
```

Is it perhaps not possible with a one-liner and I should consider writing a code to parse character by character and see if a matching word `_LN\d+_` or a character `/` is there?

Comment: You could use [tr](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr).

Comment: Try `perl -lpe 's,(_?LN\d+_?)|[^/],$1,g' file`

Comment: Work from here `s![^_LN\d/]!!g` ...

Comment: Why spaces after (some of) the slashes?  Btw, I edited the question to format input: are those supposed to be indeed two lines, or four (where two were "separated" only by a space)?

Comment: That `_LN155` is kept but it is NOT followed by `_` -- and the question says you want to keep the pattern `_LD\d+_`, with a trailing underscore ...?

Answer (score 1):

To merely remove everything other than these patterns can simply match the patterns and join the matches back

```
perl -wnE'say join "", m{/ | _LN[0-9]+_ }gx' file
```

or perhaps, depending on details of the requirements

```
perl -wnE'say join "", m{/ | _LN[0-9]+(?=_) }gx' file
```

(See explanation in the last bullet below.)

Prints, for the first line (of the two) of the shown sample input

```
/_LN0__LN3_//_LN99__LN151_
...
```

or, in the second version

```
/_LN0_LN3//_LN99_LN151_LN11/
...
```

The `_LN155` is *not* there because it is not followed by `_`. See below.

Questions:

- Why are there spaces after some `/` in the "*edited version*" shown in the question?
- The pattern to keep is shown as `_LN\d+_` but `_LN155` is shown to be kept even though it is *not* followed by a `_` in the input (but by a `/`) ...?

  Are underscores optional by any chance? If so, append `?` to them in the pattern

  ```
  perl -wnE'say join "", m{/ | _?LN[0-9]+_? }gx' file
  ```

  with output

  ```
  /_LN0__LN3__LN155//_LN99__LN151_LN11_/
  ```

  (It's been clarified that the extra space in the shown desired output is a mistake.)
- If the underscores "overlap," like in `_LN155_LN11_`, in the regex they *won't* be both matched by the `_LN\d+_` pattern, since the first one "takes" the underscore.

  But if such overlapping instances nned be kept then replace the trailing `_` with a [lookahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) for it, which doesn't consume it so it's there for the leading `_` on the next pattern

  ```
  perl -wnE'say join "", m{/ | _LN[0-9]+(?=_) }gx' file
  ```

  (if the underscores are optional and you use `_?LN\d+_?` pattern then this isn't needed)

Comment: Space & underscore for the edited version comes from my mistake.
Underscores can be treated optional. 
Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Will OK, thanks for clarifying. Then this answer has all that's needed I think.